# Subsets of different norm balls

Tags: normed-spaces

I have the following tasks:
With respect to the norms $\|x\|_1$, $\|x\|_2$, $\|x\|_{\infty}$ in $\mathbb R^2$, it  shall be shown that it holds for the norm balls $B_r(x)^{1} \subset B_r(x)^{2}\subset B_r(x)^{\infty}$.

This is intuitively clear interprating it graphically.

However, considering the norms, I obtain $\|x\|_1 \geq \|x\|_2 \geq \|x\|_{\infty}$ (simply based on Minkowski‘s inequality for p norms). The result is contrary to the subset relation of the norm balls that I have to show.

Any hint and clarifying comment would be appreciated.

Comment: That isn’t a contradiction! Try proving the subset relations using these inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

The hint in the 1st comment motivates me to try a proof as follows:

I show that $B_r^{1}\subset B_r^{2}\subset B_r^{\infty}$:

For norms $\|x\|_p$ and $\|x\|_q$ the following inequality holds:

$m\|x\|_p\leq \|x\|_q \leq M \|x\|_p$.

Let $x\in B_1^2$ (i.e., $r=1$), hence $\|x\|_2\leq1$.

Therefore, $\|x\|_2\leq \|x\|_1 \leq M \|x\|_2\leq M$.

It yields: $x\in B_M^1$ and $x\in B_1^2$.

Due to Minkowski‘s inequality for p norms it must be: $\|x\|_2\leq\|x\|_1$, which concludes that $M>1$.

Hence: $B_1^{1}\subset B_1^{2}$, or $B_r^{1}\subset B_r^{2}$.

(The same for $\|x\|_{\infty}\leq \|x\|_2 \leq M \|x\|_{\infty}$ yields $B_r^{2}\subset B_r^{\infty}$.)